# "rpm -qf file_name" is giving the package name, although that file was deleted

Tags: linux, rpm

For Suppose, i have installed a package having files file1, file2 and file3.
After installation i have removed file3.

But "rpm -qf file3" is giving the package name, even file3 was not there.
And also "rpm -ql package" is also displaying all 3 files.

How can i update rpm about that package to display only available files i.e. file1 and file2 when queried with "rpm -ql"

Comment: RPM is using a database that keeps the description of packages, included files, etc. If you install RPM and delete a file from the file-system, the description in the RPM database is not affected and it should not be. Any other person that installs that same package would like to now that there are 3 files coming from this package installation, not two. This information (list of included files) is contained in the RPM package header. Check out the RPM package format for more info.

Answer (score 1):

well if you delete the files physically, it doesn't make any in package management (you didn't remove package, just delete some file). If you want remove installed package use `yum` or `rpm` command

e.g.

```
 yum erase firefox
```

or

```
 rpm -e firefox
```

Comment: what i am asking is, if i deleted a file of a package, "rpm -ql package" is still displaying all files along with that removed file also. Is there any way to get only available files when queried about that package(excluding removed files)?

Comment: no, there is a database (as @hovanessyan pointed correctly) which gives you list of installed packages and each package has list of files. rpm -q is query on that database, not on actual state of your system. Even if you delete a file from your system, the file is still a member of the package therefore it is displayed. If you want available files, you need to make some short script, where info from rpm -q command would be linked against reality (check if the files exist in reality)

Comment: Could you please share me, that short script to check if the files exist in reality.

Comment: unfortunately, have to work now, but all you need is just make while cycle where you find out whether a particular file exists or not. You can do it in many ways in many different languages - choose what suits you best

Comment: ok. If i removed the file(mentioned in %files section) using postinstall script(i.e. %post section of spec file) instead of removing the file after installation, at this time also "rpm -ql" is giving all files instead of available files. why?. During installation i am removing the file.

Comment: hmm, I'm not familiar with packaging system so don't take theese lines for granted. It seems to me that process you described is equivalent to deleting file after the installation. Most likely there is some other list with package files ... Anyway, try to make new question where you gonna describe what you really need - maybe there is a way without doing a such strange (not recommended) things ...